# Call pip via Python Launcher

Tags: python, pip

I've installed Python 3.5 and 2.7 side by side on a Windows machine. Rather than messing around with my `PATH`, I'm using the Python Launcher to call different Python versions, for instance `py -2` if I want to use Python 2. My question is: how do I call the `pip` executable for that installation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to start `pip` as a module like

```
py -2 -m pip install virtualenv
```

Actually if you do want to mess around with python-environments (like installing conflicting libraries for the same python-version) you should take a look a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)